# Phonegap/Cordova 3.4 update gives multiple errors

Tags: ios, cordova

After upgrading to Cordova 3.4 from 3.3 I get the following error:

```
Shell Script Invocation Error Group
Cp: ....../platforms/ios/myproject/config.xml: No such file or directory
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure.
```

This is relating to the running of **cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh** from build phases.

This doesn't result in the build to fail, but still concerns me...

Anyone know a fix for this?

BTW the config.xml it can't find definitely exists.

Answer (score 1):

Remove platform and add it back again.

Remove

```
cordova platform rm ios
```

Add

```
cordova platform add ios
```